Entity Framework Core : Include not working for many-to-many relationship
I'm having trouble with .Include() not working for many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework Core. My setup works fine for one-to-many relationships, but the related entities are not being loaded for many-to-many relationships.
Entities:
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public List<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class AppRole : IdentityRole<long>
{
    public ICollection<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
{
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
    public AppRole Role { get; set; }
}

Config:
builder.Entity<AppUser>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            b.HasMany(ur => ur.UserRoles)
             .WithOne(u => u.User)
             .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId)
             .IsRequired();
        });

builder.Entity<AppRole>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            b.HasMany(ur => ur.UserRoles)
             .WithOne(u => u.Role)
             .HasForeignKey(u => u.RoleId)
             .IsRequired();
        });

builder.Entity<AppUserRole>(b =>
        {
            b.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
             .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
             .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
            b.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
             .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
             .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
        });

Query:
var users = await _userManager.Users
                              .Include(u => u.Photos)
                              .Include(u => u.UserRoles)
                              .ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role)
                              .ToListAsync();

From the query I'm expecting the list of the user with Roles. But Role list is empty. I have added roles to the user.
Note: .Include() for Photos is working fine, and it is one to many relation, but UserRoles is not working.

Include works. This is an ASP.NET Core Identity issue, not an EF Core problem. The code's problem is that it's trying to treat ASP.NET Core Identity classes as EF Core DTOs. EF Core is just one possible way to store security information. The Identity classes don't need Users and Roles properties, the mappings and relations are already defined in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore and applied by .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();. Identity knows nothing about the custom properties

Have you tried to use or customize Identity the way the docs show?

Finally, I fixed the issue.
I replaced
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, long>
{
}

to
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, long, IdentityUserClaim<long>,
    AppUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>, IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>
{
}

and it's working fine as I expected.

Observation: I have a custom AppUserRole and I need to add it to the context.

Short answer: use Select and SelectMany as suggested by the system.
However, there are some improvements possible, which make it possible to use the List<...> properties. After that I give some recommendations to improve your query.
Fetching the data using the junction table and the overload of SelectMany that has a parameter resultSelector
var usersWithTheirRolesAndPhotos = myDbContext.Users
    .Select(user => new
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,

        // use the foreign key to fetch the users's Photos
        Photos = myDbContext.Photos
            .Where(photo => photo.UserId == user.Id)
            .Select(photo => new
            {
                Id = photo.Id,
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),

        Roles = myDbContext.UserRoles
            .Where(userRole => userRole.UserId == user.Id)
            .SelectMany(
                // parameter collectionSelector:
                // for each userRole, select all roles that belong to this userRole
                userRole => myDbContext.Roles.Where(role => role.Id == userRole.RoleId)

                // parameter resultSelector: for every userRole,
                // and every role that belongs to this userRole make one new
                (userRole, role) => new
                {
                    Id = role.Id,
                    ... // other Role properties

                    // we won't use any UserRole properties
                })
                .ToList(),
    });

Possible causes why you can't use the List<...>
So there is a many-to-many relation between Users and Roles: every User has zero or more Roles, every Role is the role of zero or more Users.
When I use full entity framework, I can query "Users, each with their Roles" without any problems. However, I see some things I wouldn't do. Maybe that is the cause?
In entity framework, aDbSet<User> represents a table of Users. Class User represents one row in the table.
If I would define Users and Roles, I would have defined it like this, following the conventions:
public class User : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Every User has zero or more Photos (one-to-many?)
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

    // Every User has zero or more Roles (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role : IdentityRole<long>
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other columns

    // every Role is a Role of zero or more Users (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

For completeness the one-side of a one-too-many relation
public class Photo : Identity...
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other columns

    // every Photo is a Photo in exactly one User, using foreign key:
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
}


In entity framework the non-virtual properties represent the columns of the table, the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

A foreign key is an actual column in the table, hence it is non-virtual. The one-to-many relation and the many-to-many relation are represented by the virtual properties.
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Role> Roles {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Photo> Photos {get; set;}
}

For simplicity I removed all the superfluous prefixes, they are not part of the problem.
In full entity framework, you don't need to specify the junction table for the many-to-many relation. Because I followed the conventions, entity framework knows the relation between Users and Roles, and uses the junction table automatically.
Only if you decide to deviate from the conventions, like non-conventional names for Tables and columns, you need annotations or fluent API.
I'm not sure whether the core version can do the same.
Note that I changed the List<...> to an ICollection<...>. First of all, User.Roles[4] is not defined, you can't guarantee what's in it, so you should discourage the use of indexes. People probably won't use indexes anyway, they will use foreach. Secondly, it is better to let entity framework decide what would be the best format to transfer the requested data. This is more an efficiency thing.
For example, if your version of entity framework is very smart, then during a query of 'items with their zero or more sub-items' it will query the data 'per page' of for instance 1000 items. You can enumerate the sequence, as you would enumerate a List. Your enumerator will fetch the next 1000 items as soon as you run out of items. If during the enumeration your code decides that enumeration is not needed anymore after the first 900 items, an ICollection<...> won't have fetched all 3 million items, while a List<...> forces all items to be fetched.
An ICollection<...> contains all functionality you would want. The only thing you are missing is indexing. But since you will be using foreach rather then while (index < user.Roles.Count), you won't miss this anyway.

In entity framework, let 'many' relations always be ICollection<...>, and give entity framework the freedom to choose the best internal format for the fetched data.


caveat The above is all for entity framework. I'm not sure if this also is the case for the core version of entity framework. Please do comment with a link if you can't use virtual ICollectioni<...> in EF core

Back to your question
Requirement: Give me all Users, each User with all his Photos and Roles
If you can use the virtual properties the answer is easy.
var usersWithTheirRolesAndPhotos = myDbContext.Users

    // don't use Include, use Select
    // and Select only the properties that you plan to use
    .Select(user => new
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,

        Photos = user.Photos.Select(photo => new
        {
            // again, select only the properties that you plan to use
            Id = photo.Id,
            ...

            // foreign key not needed, you already know the value
            // UserId = photo.UserId,
        })
        .ToList(),

        Roles = user.Roles.Select(role => new
        {
            Id = role.Id,
            ...
        })
        .ToList(),
    });


Database management systems are extremely optimized to combine tables and select data from them. One of the slower parts is the transfer of the selected data to your local process. Hence it is wise to select only the properties that you actually plan to use.

If you don't want to use the virtual properties, or you cannot use them, you can use a GroupJoin or SelectMany. Use the overload with prameter resultSelector to specify the data that you want to fetch.
Why you should not use Include
If you use Include to fetch all related items, you fetch all columns of the items, inclusive the columns that you probably won't use, like foreign keys.
Every DbContext has a ChangeTracker. Whenever you fetch a complete item, this means, whenever you query data without using Select, the tem is put in the ChangeTracker, together with a copy of it. You get the reference to this copy (or maybe the original, doesn't matter). All changes you make to this reference are made to this copy.
If after a while you call SaveChanges, all properties of all originals in the ChangeTracker are compared by value with all copies. All original properties that are not equal (by value) to the copy are updated.
If you have a database of Schools with their Students, and there is a one-to-many relation between Schools and Students, you know that every Student will have a foreign key to the School he attends.
If you decide to fetch School[4] with its 2000 Students, then you know that every Student will have a foreign key to the School with value 4.
If you want to fetch this data, not to change it, only to display it, and you would use Include to fetch this School and his Students, you will transfer this value 4 over 2000 times for nothing.
Apart from that, the School and all Students are placed in the ChangeTracker. If you call SaveChanges, because you changed a Teacher, then all properties of all 2000 original Students are compared with their copies.
What a waste of processing power!

When fetching data always use Select, and select only the properties that you actually plan to use. Only user Include if you  plan to update the fetched data.

